# Convert MDB to CSV

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access mdb file. I need to convert it to a CSV file. How do i do it? Please do not point me to any freeware.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No freeware! So, you want a shopping recommendation?

Comment: @pavium..I need a block of code to convert it myself.

Comment: You can find another version of VBA code to dump tables as CSV files here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470469/how-fast-is-sqlite-compared-to-microsoft-access-mdb/6471310#6471310

Comment: two thumbs down for closing this; dataops is real.

Answer (score 6):

Another useful tool is mdbtools:

http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/

Comment: mdbtools is available on Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install mdbtools

Answer (score 4):

Being no freeware, as you requested, I could recommend you Spectral Core's [Full Convert Enterprise](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/).

I've used it successfully in the past, too.

**Update:**

Since you clarified that you need a programmatic solution, I do recommend you do it manually:

1. Open a connection to the MDB file through ADO.NET.
2. Iterate all tables.
3. Create a text file (CSV) for each table.
4. For each table, iterate all rows.
5. For each row, write a new line in the text file.
6. For each row, iterate all columns.
7. For each column, write the value to the text file in the current row.

Comment: @Keim ... I meant is that I want Code  which will do the conversion. I do not need any tool to do that. Can any one help me with that?

Comment: Thankx Keim...I did it. But Now I am stuck in a whole new situation.. Now i have to read from that CSV file and convert it in to a MDB file. Any help regarding this?

Comment: @Rajdeep Try posting a new question and/or searching the Internet for a solution.

Comment: @Keim. I didnt get your point.

Answer (score 4):

use this utility its opensource and free  mdb to csv convertor: 
[MDBtoCSV](http://mdbtocsv.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This link doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 4):

Plotly (https://plot.ly) will convert your MDB files to CSV for free.
EDIT: free Plotly users cannot use this functionality; a subscription is required.

Answer (score 3):

With VBA

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , tdf.Name, tdf.Name & ".csv"
    End If
Next
```

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220768%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: +1 Actually I prefer my version, but admit that I'm biased.  :-)  However I still think it's useful to skip dumping "~" tables to CSV, and to include field names in the CSV files.

Comment: @HansUp This is an antique question with a throw away answer :) I do not have any "~" tables, I never have had. Do you mean queries?

Comment: No, I meant tables.  When you delete a table, it persists in the TableDefs collection with its original name prefaced by "~".  I'm unsure how long they persist in that fashion; compact seems to remove them.  But I reckoned, if there is a deleted table still present in TableDefs, there wouldn't be value in saving it as CSV.

Comment: Interesting. They do not last past a close and reopen, so they must be tables very recently deleted.