# Importing AccessDB and Oracle directly into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ms-access

I am receiving **.dmp** and **.mdb** files from a customer & need to get that data into **MongoDB**.

Is there any way to straight import these file types into Mongo?

The goal is to programmatically ingest these into mongo in any way I can. The only rule is that customer will not change their method of data delivery, meaning I'm stuck with the .**dmp** and .**mdb** files as a source.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options/ideas:

1. [Convert mdb to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211786/convert-mdb-to-csv), then use `mongoimport --type csv` to import into MongoDB.
2. Use an ETL tool, e.g. Pentaho, Informatica, etc. This will give you much more flexibility for doing any necessary transformation/conversion of data.
3. Write a custom ETL tool, using libraries that know how to read mdb and dmp files.

You don't mention how you plan to use this data, how many tables are in the database, and how normalized the tables are. Depending on the specifics of your use case, it's very possible that loading the data from Access "as is" will not be a good choice since normalized schemas are not a good fit for MongoDB and MongoDB does not natively support joins. This is where an ETL tool can help, by extracting the source data and transforming it into an appropriate JSON structure.

Comment: I will begin to transform the data once I can parse it out of the .mdb and .dmp files. I was hoping that there would be a tool-free way to get it out of those file formats. I was hoping it could be pulled straight into Mongo and then I can begin the ETL process.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has released ODBC drivers. Go Here [MongoDB ODBC Drivers](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-driver-for-the-mongodb-connector-for-business-intelligence) connect MSAccess directly to MongoDB through ODBC. Voila!